# Laravel - How to add extra condition to Unique Request Rules Validation

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 validation I have this code in the Rules Request:

```
public function rules()
{       
    return [            
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:2',
            'max:80',               
            Rule::unique('units')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id);
            })                   
        ],                           
    ];        
}
```

I want to add this extra condition to the Rules Request Above:

> whereNotNull('parent_id')

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add additional condition

```
'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'min:2',
            'max:80',               
            Rule::unique('units')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
                            ->whereNotNull('parent_id');
            })                   
        ],
```

Also You can write custom validation

```
'name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'min:2',
        'max:80',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $unit=Unit::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->whereNotNull('parent_id')->exists();
            if ($unit) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
```